# How to set up key bindings to change file type in Sublime Text 2

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

I would like to learn whether it's possible to set up a key binding in Sublime Text 2 to change a file type.  To clarify further, I am not trying to alter a particular file type settings via a key binding but change the file type itself.

When I open Sublime Text 2, my default file type is plain text. This works for my needs. But I would like to create a shortcut (key binding) to be able to quickly switching to a different file type (e.g. Java or SQL). As of right now, I have to make the selection via mouse.

[image]

Thanks for any tips in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the answer if anyone is interested.

It turns out that Sublime Text 2 has a built-in functionality for switching file types in the Command Palette.

So to switch from plain text file type to xml:

1) Ctrl+Shift+P

2) type "xml"

3) select "set syntax:XML"

[image]

note: for SQL file type, type in "ssql"

It's not a single key binding answer but it certainly does the trick for my needs.